# How to call stored procedure with OUT parameter in Rails 3.2 - updated

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have created the following SP in MYSQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_BookDetailsCount(OUT bookCount INT)
BEGIN
       SELECT count(*) INTO bookCount 

       FROM books;

       SELECT bookCount;
END $$
```

And I am trying to get the SP out param value using rails 3.2.8.

My code in Model

```
count = 0 
 r = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value("CALL usp_BookDetailsCount(OUT count)")   
 return count
```

I got the following error in Browser

```
Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUT count)' at line 1: CALL usp_BookDetailsCount(OUT count)
```

But i am able to get the stored Procedure values without OUT Parameter in rails

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific AR API method for interacting with stored procedures, I'm afraid. Try #execute:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute